# Reference for Lindelöf number of topological space

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

I try to study the Lindelöf number of topological space. Are there some classical books or papers or useful links on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The classic reference for cardinal functions in topology is István Juhász, *Cardinal functions in topology*, Math. Centre Tracts 34, Amsterdam, 1971. It was superseded by his *Cardinal functions in topology: ten years later*, Math Centre Tracts 123, Amsterdam, 1980, with a second printing in 1983. Both are freely available in PDF [here](http://repository.cwi.nl/search/zoekmctracts/repository_.php): search on *cardinal functions* in the Title field. (There are also direct links to the PDFs [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_function#References).) The articles *Cardinal Functions I* and *Cardinal Functions II* by Richard Hodel and István Juhász, respectively, in the [*Handbook of Set-Theoretic Topology*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0444704310), Kenneth Kunen and Jerry E. Vaughan, eds., North-Holland, 1988, are also worth a look. All of these have copious references.

Of course all of those references are at least $25$ years old; a search on *Lindelöf degree* and *Lindelöf number* will turn up a great deal of more recent material on this and related topics. But they should still be a useful starting point.